# Comma-separated string match

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this query:

```
SELECT regexp_replace (var_called_num, '^' ||ROUTING_PREFIX) INTO Num  
FROM   INCOMING_ROUTING_PREFIX
WHERE  var_called_num LIKE ROUTING_PREFIX ||'%';`
```

INCOMING_ROUTING_PREFIX  table has two rows

```
1) 007743
2) 007742
```

`var_called_num` is `0077438843212123`. So above query gives the result `8843212123`. 
So basically, the query is removing prefix (longest match from table) from `var_called_num`.

Now my table has changed. Now it has only 1 row which is comma-separated.

Modified Table:
INCOMING_ROUTING_PREFIX  table has one row which is comma-separated:

```
1) 007743,007742
```

How to modify the query to achieve the same behavior. Need to remove longest match prefix from `var_called_num`.

Comment: Why have you changed your data model? Seems like a retrograde step... There are lots of examples of tokenizing strings around though. The reference to 'longest match' is also slightly odd, it implies you could end up with more than one match (e.g. if you also had `00774`), which would get a too-many-rows error.

Answer (score 2):

you can split the values

```
with test as (
select regexp_substr('007743,007742','[^,]+', 1, level) as ROUTING_PREFIX from dual
  connect by regexp_substr('007743,007742S', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  )
```

and that use the view in your select

```
SELECT regexp_replace ('0077438843212123', '^' ||ROUTING_PREFIX)  
  FROM test WHERE '0077438843212123' LIKE ROUTING_PREFIX ||'%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option: you'd have to split the prefix into rows, and the use it in `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

```
SQL> with
  2    calnum (var_called_num) as
  3      (select '0077438843212123' from dual),
  4    incoming_routing_prefix (routing_prefix) as
  5      (select '007743,007742' from dual),
  6  --
  7    irp_split as
  8      (select regexp_substr(i.routing_prefix, '[^,]+', 1, level) routing_prefix
  9       from incoming_routing_prefix i
 10       connect by level <= regexp_count(i.routing_prefix, ',') + 1
 11      )
 12  select regexp_replace(c.var_called_num, '^' || s.routing_prefix) result
 13  from calnum c join irp_split s on s.routing_prefix = substr(c.var_called_num, 1, length(s.routing_prefix));

RESULT
----------------
8843212123

SQL>
```

By the way, why did you change the model to a *worse* version than it was before?